# Submitted Form not POSTing Data (except for submit=>Submit )

Tags: html, forms, post, submit

I have been trying to submit data with a form to some php code. The code gets `$_POST['sumbit'] == 'Submit'` but nothing else.

Example:

```
<form id="ucp" method="post" action="./ucp.php?i=nhl&amp;mode=nhl">
<fieldset class="fields2">
<dl>
    <dt><label for="teamname">Team Name:</label></dt>
    <dd><input type="text" maxlength="25" id="teamname"></dd>
</dl>
<fieldset class="submit-buttons">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" class="button2" />&nbsp; 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button1"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
http_build_query($_POST) == "submit=Submit" || ""
```

Answer (score 8):

Forms need inputs with NAMEs, IDs will not work. Any input field without a name attribute does not send data.