# form is submit but values are not passing

Tags: javascript, html

When I submit form by using below function it is submitting but values are not passed through this function. I use all functions but nothing found:

```
document.getElementById("postad").submit();
```

Form is given below.

```
<form action="register.php" id="postad" method="post">
    <input class="textfield2" type="text" id="post_title" style="width:640px;" placeholder="Ad Title" onBlur="check('post_title')" />
    <input class="button" type="button" name="save" value="Publish" onclick="send();" />
</form>
```

Comment: Show form html and where you are getting form submit.

Comment: html code for your form pls

Comment: What value? How are you determining that it isn't being passed?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitted Form not POSTing Data (except for submit=>Submit )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765629/submitted-form-not-posting-data-except-for-submit-submit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form contains two form controls. Neither will be a successful control (i.e. one that appears in the submitted data), but for different reasons.

Only form controls with `name` attributes can be successful. Your text input doesn't have a `name`. (It also doesn't have a default value, so you need to type in it first).

Buttons can only be successful if they are the submit button used to submit the form. Your button isn't a submit button and you use JavaScript to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no name attribute in your input text fields

```
 <input name="post_title"  class="textfield2" type="text" id="post_title" style="width:640px;" placeholder="Ad Title" onBlur="check('post_title')" />
 .........^
```