# Form is submitting but not sending data via POST

Tags: php, html, forms, post

It may seem to duplicate as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887112/simple-form-not-sending-data-via-post) but it is not. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21778790/form-is-submit-but-values-are-not-passing) is also not my case for the same reason.

---

Here is my `form` code.

```
   <form id="form-box" name="formName" action="notes-uploading.php" onSubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="sub-box" align="left">
                <div class="sub-box-name">
                    <div class="box-num" align="center">1</div>
                    <div class="box-name">Notes Info</div>
                </div>

                <!-- Text [Name] -->
                <input type="text" name="naam" class="sub-box-ip-txt" placeholder="Notes/Assignment Name*" required>


                <!-- Select [Stream] -->
                <select id="select-input" name="stream" required>
                    <option value="Wrong">Choose a stream</option>
                    <option value="Science & Engineering">Science & Engineering</option>
                    <option value="Business & Management">Business & Management</option>
                    <option value="Arts & Humanity">Arts & Humanity</option>
                    <option value="Architecture">Architecture</option>
                    <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
                    <option value="Law">Law</option>
                    <option value="Competition">Competition</option>
                    <option value="Others">Others</option>
                </select>

                <div class="error" id="slctErr"></div>

                <!-- Text [Subject] -->
                <input type="text" name="subject" class="sub-box-ip-txt" placeholder="Subject Name*" required>

                <!-- Text [Topic Name] -->
                <input type="text" name="topic" class="sub-box-ip-txt" placeholder="Topic Name*" >

                <!-- Text [Course] -->
                <input type="text" name="course" class="sub-box-ip-txt" placeholder="Course*" >

                <!-- Text [Branch] -->
                <input type="text" name="branch" class="sub-box-ip-txt" placeholder="Branch*" >

                <span class="field-name">Upload Docs:</span>

                <label id="upload-btn">
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg, .pdf, .ppt, .docx, .xlsx" id="img-upload" multiple>
                   <span class="upload-button"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>Select Docs*</span>
                </label>

                <div class="error" id="uploadErr"></div>


                <textarea form="form-box" name="description" class="text-area-input" placeholder="Description"></textarea>


                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">


            </div>
        </form>
```

---

And below is the validateForm() method, as it may be the reason of the problem.

```
<script>
        function validateForm(){

            var checkForm;


            /*Validating Select*/
            var stream = document.forms["formName"]["select-input"];
            var slctErr = document.getElementById("slctErr");
            if(stream.value == "Wrong"){
                slctErr.innerHTML = "Please select a stream";
                checkForm = false;  
            }
            else{
                slctErr.innerHTML = "";
                checkForm = true;   
            }

            /*----Validating Image Upload----*/
            var files = document.getElementById("img-upload").files;
            var uploadErr = document.getElementById("uploadErr");
            if(files.length > 20){
                uploadErr.innerHTML = "Max 20 photos are allowed.";
                checkForm = false;
            }
            else if(files.length == 0){
                uploadErr.innerHTML = "Upload 1 or more photos.";   
                checkForm = false;
            }
            else{
                uploadErr.innerHTML = "";
                checkForm = checkForm && true;  
            }
            return checkForm;
        }
    </script>
```

---

I have `name` attribute in all the `input` fields of the `form`.

Below is my `notes-uploading.php` page code snippet.

```
/*if someone tries to Direct access of this page*/
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST"){
    die('Invalid Access: Page: notes-uploading.php; Line: 9'); 
 }
```

Browser prints this. I removed this line, so it shows that `index` not defined, that is the data is not received.

**Where is the problem? Why the form is submitting but not sending data via POST.**

Comment: add else part like this if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "POST"){
    die('Invalid Access: Page: notes-uploading.php; Line: 9'); 
 }
 else
 {
    print_r($_POST);  
  
 }

Comment: *"And below is the validateForm() method, as it may be the reason of the problem"* - I'm not sure how it could be the problem, but you can easily test that by (temporarily) removing the `onsubmit` attribute to see if the POST works without the function.

Comment: i tried your code in my localhost its working and i got it the $_POST array like this *Array ( [naam] => sd [stream] => Science & Engineering [subject] => sds [topic] => sdsd [course] => sdsd [branch] => sdsds [description] => sdsd [submit] => Submit )*

Comment: @JYoThI, here it is unnecessary to put `else` as the execution is ending in the `if`. It won't go in else.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah I can try it. Let me.

Comment: @JYoThI So what could be the possible reason. I think I should try it once again after restarting the server

Comment: clear you browser history  and try again . may be it will work @Siraj

Comment: I restarted my server, and tried this on different browser (MS Edge), as you said to clear my history, but it didn't helped. I have already wasted around 2 hours. No result.

Comment: In your `die()` message, you should output `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` to see what it actually is.

Comment: Like this ??
`die('Invalid Access: page this line this. reason: '.$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] )`

Comment: It is showing `GET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the bug. It was a very stupid bug. I checked my database, and the data was there, that is the data was uploading and everything was fine. And if the `die` function is in the beginning so why the `data` was being uploaded?

the problem was the last line of my `notes-uplaoding.php`

```
/*Redirection after uploading*/
header("Location: notes-uploading.php");
```

The thing is, I have put a `header` function which is redirecting it to itself, i.e. I was accessing my page twice, and the first time it was working correct and uploading data, but in the second access, it was not coming via POST. 
So just changing the content of `header` function, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkForm` when that return true what happens to the data ?? I don't see any function catching the return value and firing the data to your php I think that might be the problem.

From your feedback it seems your code is acting wired any way this what I do with my forms I use separate script to validate then submit the collected data to the php which will add them to the server.

By doing this data will be submitted using get event the method says POST look at the below 2 codes and get an idea.

HTML:

```
<body onLoad="pauseLoad()">
       <div id="divCenter" class="box">
         <form name="clientTimeSheet" id="clientTimeSheet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <label id="userName">Hello <!--User Name--></label>
             <label id="uId" hidden></label>
              <div style="width: 166px; position: absolute; left: 642px; top: 20px; height: 44px;">
                <img src="../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33"></div>
              <br><br>
             <label for="date">Date:</label>
             <label id="date" style="margin-left:43px;"></label>
         <br><br>
      <label for="catSelect">Category:</label>
          <select name="catSelect" id="catSelect" onFocus="" onChange="getClient(this.id); catId(this.id);"  style="margin-left:14px; width:180px">
          </select>
             <input type="text" id="cateId" size="1" hidden>
      <label for="clientSelect" style="margin-left:14px;">Client:</label>
          <select name="clientSelect" id="clientSelect" onChange="clientId(this.id)" style="width:180px;"></select>
             <input type="text" id="clintId" size="1" hidden>
        <br><br>
      <label for="startTime">Start Time:</label>
          <input type="text" name="startTime" id="startTime" style="margin-left:7px;" size="8" readonly>
          <button type="button" name="getStartTime" id="getStartTime" onMouseDown="getSvrTime()"  onMouseUp="startBtnDisable()">Get Time</button>
      <label for="endTime" style="margin-left:42px;">End Time:</label>
          <input type="text" name="endTime" id="endTime" size="8" readonly>
          <button type="button" name="getEndTime" id="getEndTime" onMouseDown="getSvrEndTime()" onMouseUp="endBtnDisable(); timeDifference(endTime, startTime);">Get Time</button>
      <label for="spentTime"  style="margin-left:30px;">Spent Time:</label>
          <input type="text" name="spentTime" id="spentTime" size="4" onFocus="" readonly>
        <br><br>        
      <label for="volume">Volume:</label>
          <input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" size="4" onkeyup="checkNum(this)" style="margin-left:23px;">
      <label for="noPl" style="margin-left: 35px;">No. of Product Lines:</label>
          <input type="text" name="noPl" id="noPl" size="4" onkeyup="checkNum(this)">
      <label for="remarks" style="margin-left:34px;">Remarks</label>
          <input type="text" name="remarks" id="remarks" size="31">      
         <br><br>
             <label id="msgID" hidden></label>
             <div id="msg"></div>
      <div id="sbmBtns">
          <input type="button" value="Reset" name="reset" id="reset" class="btn" onclick="resetForm()">
          <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn" onmousedown="pauseLoad2()">
      </div>
    </form>
   </div>
  </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
/**
 * Created by SiNUX on 4/4/2017.
 */
//This will submit all the data to the process PHP to add everything to the data base
function timeSheetAdd(){

    var uId = document.getElementById("uId").innerHTML,
        date = document.getElementById("date").innerHTML,
        cat = document.getElementById("cateId").value,
        clId = document.getElementById("clintId").value,
        sTime = document.getElementById("startTime").value,
        eTime = document.getElementById("endTime").value,
        spTime = document.getElementById("spentTime").value,
        vl = document.getElementById("volume").value,
        nPl = document.getElementById("noPl").value,
        rem = document.getElementById("remarks").value;

    if (cat === "" || clId ==="" || sTime === "" || eTime === "" || spTime === "" || vl === ""){

        document.getElementById("msgID").innerHTML = "2";

    }else if(spTime === "00:00:00"){

        document.getElementById("msgID").innerHTML = "4";

    }else{

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }else{

            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                document.getElementById("msgID").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","../bin/TimeSheetSubmit.php?uId="+uId+"&jdate="+date+"&cat="+cat+"&clientid="+clId+"&stTime="+sTime+"&enTime="+eTime
            +"&spnTime="+spTime+"&vol="+vl+"&pl="+nPl+"&rem="+rem,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

PHP Server Side:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SiNUX
 * Date: 4/5/2017
 * Time: 11:24 AM
 */

include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");

if($_REQUEST["uId"] != ""){

    if($_REQUEST["pl"] =="" && $_REQUEST["rem"] == ""){

        //This query will add all the data sent from the user front end form
        $addTimeSheetData = "INSERT INTO usertimetrack (jDate, usrId, Category, Client, startTime, endTime, timeSpent, Volume)
VALUES (:jdate,:uId, :cat, :clientid, :stTime, :enTime, :spnTime,:vol)";

        //Binding data to query
        $addTimeSheetQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addTimeSheetData);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':jdate',$_REQUEST["jdate"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':uId',$_REQUEST["uId"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':cat',$_REQUEST["cat"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':clientid',$_REQUEST["clientid"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':stTime',$_REQUEST["stTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':enTime',$_REQUEST["enTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':spnTime',$_REQUEST["spnTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':vol',$_REQUEST["vol"]);

    }elseif ($_REQUEST["rem"] == ""){

        //This query will add all the data sent from the user front end form
        $addTimeSheetData = "INSERT INTO usertimetrack (jDate, usrId, Category, Client, startTime, endTime, timeSpent, Volume, noOfProductLines)
VALUES (:jdate,:uId, :cat, :clientid, :stTime, :enTime, :spnTime,:vol, :pl)";

        //Binding data to query
        $addTimeSheetQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addTimeSheetData);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':jdate',$_REQUEST["jdate"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':uId',$_REQUEST["uId"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':cat',$_REQUEST["cat"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':clientid',$_REQUEST["clientid"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':stTime',$_REQUEST["stTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':enTime',$_REQUEST["enTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':spnTime',$_REQUEST["spnTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':vol',$_REQUEST["vol"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':pl',$_REQUEST["pl"]);

    }elseif ($_REQUEST["pl"] == ""){

        //This query will add all the data sent from the user front end form
        $addTimeSheetData = "INSERT INTO usertimetrack (jDate, usrId, Category, Client, startTime, endTime, timeSpent, Volume, Remarks)
VALUES (:jdate,:uId, :cat, :clientid, :stTime, :enTime, :spnTime,:vol, :rem)";

        //Binding data to query
        $addTimeSheetQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addTimeSheetData);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':jdate',$_REQUEST["jdate"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':uId',$_REQUEST["uId"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':cat',$_REQUEST["cat"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':clientid',$_REQUEST["clientid"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':stTime',$_REQUEST["stTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':enTime',$_REQUEST["enTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':spnTime',$_REQUEST["spnTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':vol',$_REQUEST["vol"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':rem',$_REQUEST["rem"]);


    }else{

        //This query will add all the data sent from the user front end form
        $addTimeSheetData = "INSERT INTO usertimetrack (jDate, usrId, Category, Client, startTime, endTime, timeSpent, Volume, noOfProductLines, Remarks)
VALUES (:jdate,:uId, :cat, :clientid, :stTime, :enTime, :spnTime,:vol, :pl, :rem)";

        //Binding data to query
        $addTimeSheetQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addTimeSheetData);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':jdate',$_REQUEST["jdate"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':uId',$_REQUEST["uId"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':cat',$_REQUEST["cat"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':clientid',$_REQUEST["clientid"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':stTime',$_REQUEST["stTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':enTime',$_REQUEST["enTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':spnTime',$_REQUEST["spnTime"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':vol',$_REQUEST["vol"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':pl',$_REQUEST["pl"]);
        $addTimeSheetQuery -> bindParam(':rem',$_REQUEST["rem"]);

    }


    if($addTimeSheetQuery -> execute()){
        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo "10";
    }

}else{
    echo "3";
}
```

Comment: In the `form` tag `onSubmit` attribute, return value is checked and the data is submitted if `checkForm` is true and not otherwise.

Comment: BTW this seems more suitable as a comment rather than the answer.

Comment: I can't directly comment to your post due to lesser rep only my answers can be commented by me sorry.

Comment: Did you try by changing POST to REQUEST in your PHP ?

Comment: like how? @Jack

Comment: `/*if someone tries to Direct access of this page*/
 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "REQUEST"){
    die('Invalid Access: Page: notes-uploading.php; Line: 9'); 
 }`

Comment: It is showing a strange thing. When I wrote 
`if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] != "REQUEST"){ die('Invalid Access: Page: notes-uploading.php; Line: 9');}`

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] ` is printing `POST` and when I'm comparing it with the post, it is printing the `GET`3