# Rails form_for with multiple submit buttons has params[:commit] returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a Rails form containing two submit buttons as follows:

```
  <%= f.submit 'Save and Add New Task' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save and Finish' %>
```

This is the code that handles the request and points to the right action:

```
  def create_split
    byebug
    define_task
    respond_to do |format|
      new_task = @task #saves in new_task the task created by the user
      load_new_task_attributes #loads everything needed for generating a new form for creating new tasks in this split
      opr = InstantiationOperator.find_by name: "split"
      @operator = opr.name
      @operator_id = opr.id
      @iteration = Iteration.find(new_task.iteration_id)
      @project = @iteration.project
      @instances = @iteration.project.instances
      @activity = Activity.find(task_activity_params[:activity_id])
      if new_task.save
        if params[:newtask]
          format.html {render :split, notice: 'Task successfully created. Go ahead and add a new one'}
        elsif params[:finish]
          format.html { redirect_to new_task.iteration, notice: 'Task successfully created.' }
        end
      else
        format.html {render :split}
      end
    end
  end
```

It always go to the `else`block though. 
I used byebug and discovered that `params[:commit]` is getting `nil`.

Then, I tried a different approach:

```
  <%= f.submit 'Save and Add New Task', name: 'newtask' %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save and Finish', name: 'finish' %>
```

And

```
  if params[:newtask]
      format.html {render :split, notice: 'Task was successfully created. Go ahead and add a new one'}
  else
      format.html { redirect_to new_task.iteration }
  end
```

Again, it only goes to the `else` block.
I checked `params[:newtask]` with byebug and it also has a `nil` value.

I believe it must be something simple, I haven't found anything relevant on the Internet yet though.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

More controller details:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create_split
    byebug
    define_task
    respond_to do |format|
      new_task = @task #saves in new_task the task created by the user
      load_new_task_attributes #loads everything needed for generating a new form for creating new tasks in this split
      opr = InstantiationOperator.find_by name: "split"
      @operator = opr.name
      @operator_id = opr.id
      @iteration = Iteration.find(new_task.iteration_id)
      @project = @iteration.project
      @instances = @iteration.project.instances
      @activity = Activity.find(task_activity_params[:activity_id])
      if new_task.save
        if params[:newtask]
          format.html {render :split, notice: 'Task successfully created. Go ahead and add a new one'}
        elsif params[:finish]
          format.html { redirect_to new_task.iteration, notice: 'Task successfully created.' }
        end
      else
        format.html {render :split}
      end
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description, :priority, :category, :status, :startDate, :comments, :TTC, :iteration_id,:instance_id, task_artifacts_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :_destroy])
    end

    #This is called before any task creation method is started
    def define_task
      @task = Task.new(task_params)
      @task.endDate = calculate_endDate(@task)
      @task.task_activities << TaskActivity.new(activity_id: task_activity_params[:activity_id], instantiation_operator_id: task_activity_params[:instantiation_operator_id])
      @task.task_actor_roles << TaskActorRole.new(task_role_id: task_actor_role_params[:task_role_id] , task_actor_id: task_actor_role_params[:task_actor_id] )
    end
end
```

Whole View:

```
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li>1- Select project, iteration and operator</li>
    <li class="active">2- Create task - split operator</li>
  </ol>

  <h1>New Task - Split Operator</h1>

  <%= render 'task_form_header' %>

  <p>Activity: <%= @activity.name %></p>

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <%= form_for(@task, url: {action: 'create_split'}, html: {class: "task"}) do |f| %>
      <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- this div will be closed inside the form fields partial !-->
      <%= hidden_field :task_activity, :activity_id, :value => @activity.id %>
      <%= hidden_field :task_activity, :instantiation_operator_id, :value => @operator_id %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :project, :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :iteration_id, :value => @iteration.id %>

      <div class="field form-group instance">
        <%= label_tag :instance, "Select an instance" %>
        <%= f.select :instance_id,@instances.collect{ |i| [i.name, i.id ]}, {prompt: "Select"}, id: "new_task_instance", required: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <%= render 'form_fields', f: f %>

      <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
        <%= f.submit 'Save and Add New Task', name: 'newtask', class: "btn btn-default submit-task" %>
        <%= f.submit 'Save and Finish', name: 'finish', class: "btn btn-default submit-task" %>
        <%= link_to 'Cancel', new_task_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>


  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you're omitting a piece of code? that should work in both ways.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma A more detailed piece of code here: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/3b678/2

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the problem as well. I have no idea why the parameters in the controller can not get a button name named params, my case should be `params[:qf_submit_and_continue]` or `params[:qf_submit]`

I investigated a lot of references. Maybe it is here is its reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/21778856/7262646

I also tried to reset a new ROR project. In the new project, I have to do nothing special, but I can get the parameters in the controller.

After struggling for a long time, I fix it and hope it can help you. ***but if you know a better way to fix it. Please feel free to let me know.***

**what I did:**

```rb
$("form").removeEvents();
```

**Side effect**

it will remove any custom validations.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Let your form be like this

```
<% form_for(something) do |f| %>
   ..
   <%= f.submit 'Save and Add New Task' %>
   <%= f.submit 'Save and Finish' %>
   ..
<% end %>
```

You controller action should be like this code snippet

```
def some_action
   if params[:commit] == 'Save and Add New Task'
      # your code goes here
   elsif params[:commit] == 'Save and Finish'
      # your code goes here
   end
end
```

**OR**

If you use submit button with name

```
 <%= f.submit 'Save and Add New Task', name: 'newtask' %>
 <%= f.submit 'Save and Finish', name: 'finish' %>
```

You controller action should be like this code snippet

```
 if params[:newtask]
   # your code goes here
 elsif params[:finish]
   # your code goes here
 end
```

Comment: I am following the second option. Still doesn't work. It returns a nil value for both params[:newtask] and params[:finish]. So when I submit my form I get the error: "ActionController::UnknownFormat".

Comment: Can you please edit your questions with details form and controller action, seems you have some bug in respond_to block?

Comment: just added more details