# My PhP file is not picking up the variables from my HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

i have created a form with a PHP file, this is for a booking request and the aim is to get the variables sent to an email address. But for some reason the variables.

Below is the code for my html arm:

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Book your Journey</legend>
            <label for ="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="number" id="number" name="number">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email">
            <label for="pickup">Pick Me Up From</label>
            <input type="text" id="pickup" name="pickup">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date">
            <label>Time:</label>
            <select>
                <option>--HR--</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
            <label>:</label>
            <select>
                <option>--MIN--</option>
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
            </select>
            <select>
                <option value="am">am</option>
                <option value="pm">pm</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="destination"> Destination Postal Code </label>
            <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination">
        </fieldset>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

and now my php code for this form is as follows

```
<?php

$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Booking';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pickup = $_POST['pickup'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$date = $_POST['date'];


$message = <<<Eod
Hi, please pick up $name from $pickup and drop to $destination
Eod;

$header = $email;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);


echo "Message Sent";

?>
```

Now, when i receive the email i can see only $destination gets picked up. Have i done something wrong in my html, it looks fine to me. Also, how do i get my select elements as a variable.

Comment: Your button needs the attribute `type = "submit"`

Comment: @GerritLuimstra [The button element's default type is submit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: Side note: Your `$header` doesn't do anything really. It just echos an email and will be rejected and fail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887112/simple-form-not-sending-data-via-post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765629/submitted-form-not-posting-data-except-for-submit-submit

Comment: `mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);` is interpreted as `mail($to, $subject, $message, email@example.com);`. I'm surprised nobody didn't pick up on that (yet). No idea if you even read these or anybody else, given the answers so far.

Comment: yeah, nobody's paying attention to that ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- I read every single comment and i really appreciate the help i get on Stack Overflow

Comment: @j08691 Didn't know that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The form fields you want to capture the value of must all have `name` attributes and they should match what you use in PHP. For example `$_POST['user_email']` not `$_POST['email']`. Note that none of your `<select>` elements have the `name` attribute.

Comment: But `name` and `pickup` elements are in the form.

Comment: did you check my comments under their question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah there are a few inconsistencies in the OP's question. Sigh

Comment: @j08691 Seems like *cat got the OP's tongue* or is AWOL.

Answer (score 0):

If destination already gets through, you do most likely have some mistake in the naming of the `name` attribute. Make sure it matches 1:1 the names you try to get in your PHP.

Secondary, regarding your `select`, you can get the value via the `name` attribute the same way you get all the text elements. Inputs, in whatever form (except of files), are just strings which do get through the protocol. It does not make any difference for PHP if the UI is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="form-control" name="hour">
   <option>--HR--</option>
   <option value="1">01</option>
   <option value="2">02</option>
   <option value="3">03</option>

</select>
<label>:</label>
<select class="form-control" name="minutes">
   <option>--MIN--</option>
   <option value="00">00</option>
   <option value="15">15</option>
   <option value="30">30</option>
   <option value="45">45</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="time_of_day">
   <option value="am">am</option>
   <option value="pm">pm</option>
</select>
```

in php:

```
//grab the value the user select for hour from the $_POST, which is an array which stores all values submitted via the post method 

$hour = $_POST['hour'];
$minutes = $_POST['minutes'];
$time_of_day = $_POST['time_of_day'];
//concate your variable to output what the user selected so it would out put something like 4:30 pm
$time = $hour.':'.$minutes.''.$time_of_day;
```

Essentially, you are adding the name attribute to the select statement like what you did for you inputs and you are accessing them the same way via php. if you do `die(var_dump($_POST));` you will see have thing that has been submitted. If you do not see it in the dump then you either know you need to revisit the code

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

You omitted the **name attributes** in the select options. I added **hour, min and periods**. Also you had **user_email value** in the name attribute for **email input field**.

In the PHP code, i've assigned concatenated and assigned the **POST 
values** for the time and updated the message

```
 <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Book your Journey</legend>
            <label for ="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            <label for="number">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="number" id="number" name="number">
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="user_email">
            <label for="pickup">Pick Me Up From</label>
            <input type="text" id="pickup" name="pickup">
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date">
            <label>Time:</label>
            <select name="hour">
                <option>--HR--</option>
                <option value="1">01</option>
                <option value="2">02</option>
                <option value="3">03</option>
                <option value="4">04</option>
                <option value="5">05</option>
                <option value="6">06</option>
                <option value="7">07</option>
                <option value="8">08</option>
                <option value="9">09</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
            </select>
            <label>:</label>
            <select name="min">
                <option>--MIN--</option>
                <option value="00">00</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="45">45</option>
            </select>
            <select name="period">
                <option value="am">am</option>
                <option value="pm">pm</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="destination"> Destination Postal Code </label>
            <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination">
        </fieldset>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
        $to = 'test@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Booking';

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['number'];
    $email = $_POST['user_email'];
    $pickup = $_POST['pickup'];
    $destination = $_POST['destination'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $time = $_POST['hour'].':'.$_POST['min'].''.$_POST['period'];
echo "Message Sent";

?>
```

Hope this helps